# CSS3 Transition of HTML5 progress bar element

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, css-transitions, css-animations

I am using a progress bar as described here:

> http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Using the `<progress>` element and styling it with the pseudo classes
`-webkit-progress-bar` and `-webkit-progress-value`.

So now I want to animate the `progress-value`, whenever it updates.

In my theory this should work via transitioning its CSS width attribute like this:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    transition: 5s width;
}
```

But for some reason this does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I don't think this works. As such, I don't quite understand why the answer below has been accepted. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600048

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [transition property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) is:

```css
transition: [property] [duration] [timing-function] [delay];
```

then your value ( `transition: 5s width;` ) is wrong, timing and property are inverted, and timing function is missing. It should be (for example):

```css
transition : width 5s ease;
```

It should also be prefixed to work crossbrowser, especially for WebKit based browsers, leaving the standard property as the last one.

```css
-webkit-transition : width 5s ease;
   -moz-transition : width 5s ease;
     -o-transition : width 5s ease;
        transition : width 5s ease;
```