# How to animate a HTML5 progress bar with CSS?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, css-transitions

When we click on the following HTML `<progress>` element, its value changes to 200.

But no animation works:

```css
progress {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    animation: progress 1s ease;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<progress value="0" onclick="this.value=200" max="1000"></progess>
```

**How to animate a HTML `<progress>` bar with CSS transition?**

Linked but not duplicate: [HTML5 progress bar animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078726/html5-progress-bar-animation),  [CSS3 Transition of HTML5 progress bar element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408442/css3-transition-of-html5-progress-bar-element)

Also, the main answer of [Animating Progress Element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588284/animating-progress-element-value) (using jQuery and custom JS), doesn't wok here, with just CSS transition/animation.

Comment: try with `animation: progress 5s ease;`

Comment: @ScriptHost I just edited my question to include your line of code, it still doesn't work, does the snippet work for you?

Comment: You're trying to add a transition on width, however the attribute that's changing is value so it doesn't animate. Only certain css properties can be animated. In the  case of a progress  HTML Element, here is how you animate it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588284/animating-progress-element-value

Comment: Now if you don't absolutely need to use a progress element, you could easily replicate it using two divs, an outside one with a grey background, an inside one with a blue background, you set the inside's width as a percentage of the outside's width and then you can animate on the inside div's width

Comment: @Emilien Thanks but I would like to keep a `<progress>` element, and no manual creation with a few `div`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that no `background-color` was defined (!).

**Without** (animation non-working):

```css
progress {
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<progress value="0" onclick="this.value=200" max="1000"></progess>
```

**With** (animation working):

```css
progress {
    background-color: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<progress value="0" onclick="this.value=200" max="1000"></progess>
```